# Полнотекстовый поиск

Tags: mysql

Хочу реализовать полнотекстовый поиск элементов. Есть таблица blog, в ней столбец text имеет индекс полнотекстовый. Выполняю запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST ('HMTL')
```

Слово HTML в тексте есть, даже есть запись, где поле text состоит из одного только слова HTML. Возвращает 0 строк всегда (ошибку не выдает).

Полнотекстовым никогда не пользовался, только сейчас появилась необходимость. Расскажите, что не так?

Делал согласно примерам с документации: [полнотекстовый поиск в MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. тип таблицы должен быть MyISAM
2. поле text должно иметь индекс `FULLTEXT`, и только оно, в случае необходимости нескольких столбцов их необходимо объединить в один индекс `FULLTEXT` и все указывать через запятую в `MATCH`
3. искомое слово, по умолчанию, должно быть больше 4-х символов. чтобы изменить этот лимит то нужно в настройках MySQL в файле `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (linux) изменить, или, если отсутствует, добавить параметр: `ft_min_word_len=1` (или другую необходимую минмальную длину слова)

Comment: Тип таблицы подходит, индекс стоит у того поля, по которому ищу. Слово более 4 тоже не дало.

Comment: попробуйте `AGAINST ('sometext' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` ,если не поможет, значит ошибка в синтаксисе где-то. я бы реккомендовал потестить запрос в phpMyAdmin

Comment: Сработало, вывело все, содержащие html. Погуглил, что те записи не слишком релевантны для выдачи, потому что база не очень хороша для поиска. Все разобрался. Забил таблицу левыми записями, и тогда html нашелся, так как стал редким.

Answer (score 4):

Вот только что заметил, что ищите Вы **HMTL**, а не **HTML** :)

Comment: 4 раза просмотрел вопрос, пару раз перечитал комментарии, полез в гугл искать - самому же интересно почему не работает)) и вот в очередной раз увидел опечатку...

Comment: @Vitalii Maslianok ну **HTML** тоже не найдет, ограничение на 4 символа свое возьмет. но основная ошибка мне кажется кроется именно в этом ) плюсую

Comment: ошибка в релевантности запроса. HTML слишком неуникален в таблице