# Оптимальная организация хранения информации в базе данных для поиска строк по массиву ключевых слов

Tags: mysql, база-данных

С тем, чтобы найти строку в таблице по какому-нибудь уникальному ключу (например, "автомобиль"), проблем нет. Но как следует организовать хранение данных в таблице, чтобы **быстро** искать данные по массиву ключевых слов (например, "автомобиль красный" или "автомобиль москва" или "москва автомобиль кредит")?

Мы хотим получить, в одних случаях, строки таблицы, которые имеют совпадения по максимальному числу ключевых слов, в других случаях - строки таблицы, отсортированные по количеству совпадений (то есть сначала идут строки, имеющие совпадения по всем трём ключевым словам из "москва автомобиль кредит", далее - строки, имеющие совпадения только по двум словам из этих, и так далее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы пытаетесь сделать - полнотекстовый поиск с ранжированием.

В MySQL есть `MATCH`, но он работает только на столбцах, по которым построен индекс, например `FULLTEXT (title,body)`. Ранее использовалось на MyISAM, [теперь доступно и в Innodb 5.6+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html).

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('москва автомобиль кредит');
```

[Подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/95537/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA)

Но будут проблемы с морфологией слов: `в москве` уже не найдут. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810678/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-mysql)  предлагают весь текст обработать (стемминг), и уже искать по этому тексту. Так себе решение.

Качеством поиска вы скорее всего будете не довольны. Дело в том, что базы данных не заточены под полнотекстовый поиск и ранжирование, они эволюционируют в других направлениях.

### Правильное решение

Поэтому следует использовать специальные решения: Sphinx, его форк Mandragora, или ElasticSearch.

Для Sphinx есть [SQL-подобный язык](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-select.html), подключение также идет через интерфейс MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('москва автомобиль кредит');
```

Вам нравится? Используйте.

Еще фишки Сфинкса:

- [rt-индекс](https://ruhighload.com/real+time+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B+%D0%B2+sphinx%27e) позволяет обновлять индекс Сфинкса "на лету". Обновили новость в MySQL? Второй командой обновите rt-индекс
- [сниппеты](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-call-snippets.html) - "подстветка" ключевиков в найденном тексте
- фасетный поиск

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Предложенные Вами инструменты незаменимы при поиске по статьям, новостям и так далее. Но всё же, анализ текста в ячейке таблицы целиком - не всегда рационально.Например, я не знаю, как реализован поиск в Evernote, но вообще там заметки можно искать только по меткам, а не по содержимому. В таком случае разумно сохранить метки в ячейку БД в виде сериализованного массива, с которым работать гораздо легче, тем с текстом. Какие-нибудь есть инструменты для данного случая?

Comment: `но он работает только на MyISAM` у вас сильно устарели сведения. fulltext search завезли в innodb ещё в 5.6. По качеству поиска, впрочем, не знаю, были ли улучшения.

Comment: @Мелкий, спасибо, поправил. @БоковГлеб, я не знаю что внутри Evernote, но похоже, [Lucene](https://evernote.com/blog/part-1-our-options-to-migrate/) `Search Index – Server side Lucene search index for user content`, на основе которой, опять же, сделан Elasticsearch. Вам нужны теги? Запишите их как `:москва:автомобиль:кредит:` и ищите в MySQL через `LIKE '%:москва:%' OR ...`. Хотите морфологию и ранжирование? Ответ выше.